How Flink CEP sorts events
In this question written: "CEP always sorts its input by timestamp".
Can you tell me where exactly in the cep library code the sorting takes place?
Is there any way to control this sorting, disable it, enlarge the window, etc

The sorting is done in the CEP operator, and only when operating in event time mode. It relies on the watermarks to know when events can safely be released from the initial sorting stage of the operator into the pattern matching stage.
Late events aren't used for pattern matching, but can be sent to a side output, if you are using the DataStream API. See the docs for details. To reduce the likelihood of late events, configure your watermarking to use a longer delay.
To disable this sorting, with Flink SQL you can use a processing time time attribute with match_recognize. With the DataStream API, use processing time via the inProcessingTime method on PatternStream, e.g.:
CEP.pattern(input, pattern)
    .inProcessingTime()

To customize the sorting, use an EventComparator (docs):
DataStream<Event> input = ...;
Pattern<Event, ?> pattern = ...;
EventComparator<Event> comparator = ...; // optional

PatternStream<Event> patternStream = CEP.pattern(input, pattern, comparator);

This only affects secondary sorting; the primary sort is always by timestamp.
